# How to obtain the equivalent of IActiveScript::InterruptScriptThread in V8?

Tags: c++, node.js, v8

The old `IActiveScript` COM interface had a wonderful method: `InterruptScriptThread`, which could be called from any thread to throw an exception in the main JS thread, even when it was in an infinite loop.

Is there a way to do the same thing with V8?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about IActiveScript, but V8 has [`v8::Isolate::TerminateExecution`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:v8/include/v8.h;l=9148?q=TerminateExecution), which sounds like what you're looking for. It causes an "uncatchable" (by JavaScript) exception to be thrown, so this exception will propagate all the way to your embedder, where you can decide how to proceed.

Termination requests are recoverable, so you can still use the `Isolate` after having terminated the previous request it was processing.

You can find a few usage examples in V8's `test/cctest/test-api.cc`.

Comment: Will accept when tried in real world (in my c++ binary module for nodejs)

Comment: My "embedder" is `nodejs`. I want to detect infinite loop ala `while ( true )`. I have a POC with a simple worker thread listening to heartbeat message. When infinite loop is "detected" my POC uses `process.kill(process.pid)`. The "uncatchable" (by JavaScript) prevents me from accepting the answer. But thanks anyway!

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize this was about Node. Maybe this answer helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60623418/is-there-any-programmatic-way-to-break-infinite-loop-in-nodejs

Comment: I did tag the question `node.js`. The other question you linked is exactly my problem. Currently playing with worker thread. Again, thanks!